# How to disable remark "LOOP WAS VECTORIZED" written by Intel compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, report, intel, icc, remarks

I want to disable remark "LOOP WAS VECTORIZED" written by Intel compiler.
But I don't want to disable optimazation.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `-vec_report` sorry, I don't have `icc` installed right now.

```
   -vec_report[n] Control amount of vectorizer diagnostic information:

                  n=0 -- No diagnostic information

                  n=1 -- Indicate vectorized loops (DEFAULT)

                  n=2 -- Indicate vectorized/non-vectorized loops

                  n=3 -- Indicate vectorized/non-vectorized loops and pro-
                  hibiting data dependence information

                  n=4 -- Indicate non-vectorized loops

                  n=5  --  Indicate  non-vectorized  loops and prohibiting
                  data dependence information
```

Comment: i don't mind, i was really wondering whereas there is a funky badge